# Powershell won't start, fails with 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name input'

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

I have a brand  new install of Windows 8.1 with Visual Studio.

Running Powershell opens a window that closes immediately. Launching `powershell` from `cmd.exe`, I get the following error:

```
Windows PowerShell failed with the following error:

Value cannot be null. 

Parameter name: input
```

I suspect the .net install has screwed up whatever version powershell uses. But all the answers I can find about this error are for developing cmdlets etc.

Comment: How are you launching PowerShell exactly? try running it directly from C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0 will it open?

Comment: I'm launching it from cmd.exe, as mentioned in the question. `cd`ing into  the dir mentioned and running `powershell.exe` returns the same message.

Comment: OK, and if you go to C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0 and run PowerShell there, what happens? That's really the meat of the question. Also, your body is ambiguous with: `Running Powershell opens a window that closes immediately.` and then `Launching powershell from cmd.exe`

Comment: `cd`ing into the dir does the same thing. I initially launched powershell from the GUI, where it did not produce an error message. I subsequently launched it from cmd to get the error message shown.

Comment: does it go away after uninstall visual studio ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 8.1 includes the Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1, so that should not be an issue. Have you tried running PowerShell with the `-NoProfile` parameter? In case you have a Windows PowerShell profile, this will prevent the execution of that profile script, and may solve the issue.

You might also want to try running (from `cmd.exe`) the following command, just to see if you get any output:

```
powershell.exe -Command Get-Process;
```

Comment: In the end, I ended up reinstalling Windows - I didn't trust the install. The problem is solved. However I've marked this as the correct answer, as I suspect either Visual Studio or Expression Blend created a broken profile. Sorry I can't upvote, I'm too new!

Comment: Glad to hear you're working now, thanks! By the way, Visual Studio should not create a PowerShell profile script, that I'm aware of ... I have no idea what the root cause of your situation was, but that seems unlikely. I thought maybe you had created a custom profile script.